# Enabling/disabling two-factor authentication in runtime

Tags: openam, two-factor-authentication

we have openAM set up with two-factor authentication using one time SMS code which worked fine up till now. Unfortunately the requirements from the client's side have changed and we would like to be able to disable/enable two-factor authentication (SMS/no-SMS) at runtime by parameter set/unset in another system (through openAM API).
Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

OpenAM offers Service Management API (which is also used by 'ssoadm') which you can use to change authentication chain etc. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.